# Data Types in Rest Client

Tags: types, format, swagger, rest-client

My swagger file says , Biller Service has variables like

```
"completionTime": "HH:mm"
"officeOnlyFlag" : "Y"
"dueDate": "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Here the type is String and format is "HH:mm" which is date format for completionTime. officeOnlyFlag has type String and takes values "Y" or "N" like boolean type.

In my client class , Should I specify variable as String completionTime ?

I specified String for completionTime variable , but I am getting 404 Error. I am not sure if it is because of data type in client class for completionTime or something else . I have huge response from biller service, so not sure what causing issue. But, at the same time, i need to clarify about the data type that I am specifying in my client class.

Answer (score 1):

In my pojo, I used JsonFormat to define the formatting as below. officeOnlyFlag is String. So, I didn't add any format.

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm")
    private Date completionTime; 
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dueDate;
    private String officeOnlyFlag;
```